# Vector artwork for UIButton or UIImageView using a PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, uiview, uiimage, uikit

Does iOS support PDFs for UI elements (`UIButton`, etc) out of the box so that multiple device resolutions are handled transparently without providing @2x assets in fixed resolution PNG bitmaps?

It should also allow `UITableViewCell` supporting "Dynamic Type" and render the `[tableViewCell imageView]` at a size matching the user's preferences instead of the standard 44 x 44 pixels.

I've not found anything about this other than code for [rendering PDFs in a `CGContextRef`](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/06/rendering-pdf-is-easier-than-you-thought/), which would do the trick, but isn't the baked in support I'm hoping for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Vector` type for images in Image Assets.

Comment: Hi Davide, thanks. Would you be able to add some further detail about this? Are there any implications, or does it "just work"?

Comment: Ah! There's lots more information and lots of detail about the implications in [this blog post](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/).

Comment: It "just works". Though, notice that they won't be treated as vector assets at runtime (in iOS) but that is only a nice way of making Xcode render the various scale versions of each image at compile-time.